# How to commit a transaction after insert on WSO2 Data Services

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have created a query to insert data into an Oracle Database Table (12c), and I have also created an operation on WSO2 ESB DSS to expose this query via WebServices. I am getting back the following response from my WSO2 call:

```
{
    "REQUEST_STATUS": "SUCCESSFUL"
}
```

However, when I look in the database, my data has not been inserted. How do I do a commit after the insert so that the data is written to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this property in the configuration for the data service.

```
<property name="autoCommit">true</property>
```

Comment: Let me try it and will get back to you.